# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}}{a^2 + \log^2 x}\, \mathrm d x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate this integral

$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}}{a^2 + \log^2 x}\, \mathrm d x$$

for $a \in \mathbb R_{>0}$.

Any ideas?

In the case $a=\pi$ we have $I= F - e$ where $F$ is the Fransén–Robinson constant.

Comment: any own thoughts?

Comment: @tired No ideas

Comment: Is there a reason to believe this integral has a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, as there is a closed form in the case $a= \pi$

Comment: It might be worth putting that in the question, @Sekots

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right-ho

Comment: @tired: Before asking the OP for "any own thoughts" (as one would do for new users of MSE who have not learned yet the rules of this community), you should have noted his reputation points and number of badges: he is clearly an experienced user, who doesn't need to be reminded to post the context of his questions. If he has chosen to post this as it is, he surely has his reasons. Besides, evaluating an integral might not always have a context, or it might have one too long to explain.

Comment: When I see $x, \Bbb e ^x$ and $\log x$ in the same integral I don't even bother to think of a solution... :) Anyway, claiming that $a - \pi$ leads to a closed form is subjective: I too can define your integral to be "the AlexM. constant", and here you are, you have a closed form.

Comment: @AlexM. Well I would consider the Fransén–Robinson constant to be rather "closed" since it is merely the integral of the reciprocal of the gamma function. The gamma function is a very common and important function about which a lot is known.

Comment: Can you add some links or details that show how the case $a=\pi$ is solved. That might be helpful. :)

Comment: @H.R.: I added a copy of Ramanujan's work from Hardy's book (I didn't find them online).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an answer but a complement to the obtention of the [Fransén–Robinson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant) by Ramanujan (i.e. the case $a=\pi$ in Hardy's book "Ramanujan" $11.10$). Not sure it will help much here but...

The Formula C  referenced is :
$$\phi(0)+\phi(1)+\phi(2)+\cdots=\int_0^\infty \phi(x)\,dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{\phi(0)-x\phi(1)+x^2\phi(2)-\cdots}{x\;(\pi^2+(\log\,x)^2)}dx$$
and the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) is from Wikipedia.

[image: p195]
[image: p196]
[image: p197]

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the exact title of this book?

Comment: (+1) Now, I am convinced that answering this question may take lots of time! :D Thanks for added details. :)

Comment: Glad it helped a little @Sekots and H.R.! The complete title of the book by G.H. Hardy is ["Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work"](http://www.amazon.com/Ramanujan-Lectures-Subjects-Suggested-Publishing/dp/0821820230). Excellent continuation,

Comment: PS: The reference to Hardy's book was found in Finch's article about the Fransén–Robinson constant [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA262) ($J(y)'$ gives a more general formula). Fransen's papers are freely available at [AMS](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1980-34-150/S0025-5718-1980-0559204-5/S0025-5718-1980-0559204-5.pdf),  [AMS'](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-37-155/S0025-5718-1981-0616377-4/S0025-5718-1981-0616377-4.pdf) and [AMS"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-42-166/S0025-5718-1984-0736456-3/S0025-5718-1984-0736456-3.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

This is more a comment/hint than a real answer, but it's too long for the comment section.

First do the substitution $e^u = x$, so that $dx = e^udu$ and your integral becomes
$$\color{red}{-}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\color{red}{(-}e^u\color{red}{)}e^{-e^u}\frac{1}{a^2+u^2}du.$$
Now you could try to substitute using the Lambert $W$ function to get rid of the first term:
$$W(z) = -e^u,\qquad du = \frac{1}{W(z)}\frac{1}{z+e^{W(z)}}dz$$
(if I worked that out correctly), and your integral takes the form
$$\int_{\color{red}{?}}^{\color{red}{?}}\frac{z~dz}{(a^2+\log(-W(z))^2)W(z)(z+e^{W(z)})}.$$
Now this is of course very ugly, but maybe it can be used somehow. Honestly, I have no idea. Where is @Cleo when you need her?

Comment: I don't think partial fraction is applicable to exponential or logarithmic functions! It seems that you just complicated the integral! :)

Comment: @H.R. Yeah, you're probably right... I will change my last sentence.

Comment: From my experience, I don't think a person gets notified if they are referred to inside an answer,  as you have done with @Cleo - although they are if the name appears in a comment,  so I am doing so here...

Comment: @CarlMummert You're right. It's done.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this answer is not a complete on but I have not enough reputation to put this as comment. If some admin cares to change this to a comment, please do so.

The standard approach to such a thing would be to look at the integral as part of a closed path integral. Let $R_0, R_1>0$, $R_0\rightarrow 0,\;\; R_1 \rightarrow \infty$ and integrate from $I_1=\int_{R_0}^{R_1}$ along the real axis, a quarter circle back at $r=R_1$ $I_2=\int_{0}^\frac\pi{2}$, down the imaginary line $I_3=-\int_{R_0}^{R_1}$ and on a quater circle with $r=R_0\;\;I_4=-\int_0^\frac\pi{2}$. Observe that for $a>\frac\pi 2$ there are no poles inside the closed integration path.

Hope this helps someone else to come up with a proper answer.

Comment: Mmh, I thought about that contour, but the part on the imaginary axis looks as ugly as the one on the real axis, so I have some doubts it will work... Have you tried working it out?

Comment: Regrettably I am totally out of practice of calculating things, otherwise I would really try to to calculate instead of giving hints. The main point is (if this approach works at all) to estimate away most of the path integrals.

Comment: Yes, and it's possible that the two quarters of circle will go away. However, I think this will not work for the vertical part of the contour. Of course I might be wrong.

Comment: I share your doubts. The enumerator of $I_3$ is $e^{-ir}$ and limited by 1. The denominator tends to infinity on both ends but may spoil any estimation by what it does in between.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it makes you go further, but with a couple of substitutions I arrived at this expression:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}}{a^2 + \log^2 x}\, \mathrm d x = K \int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-t}}{\pi^2 + \log^2 t}e^{-t^{-q}-1}t^{-q-1}\, \mathrm d x
$$

It is nice because it seems to mix the integral of $\Gamma$ with the integral of its inverse.

If you need I'll double-check the calculations to give you the correct values for $K$, while $q=\pi/a$.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't obtain a closed form but searched the expansions of $I(a)$ at $+\infty$ and $0$.
The function is smooth with some resemblance with a (faster decreasing) rectangular hyperbola.

**Formal expansion as $\;a\to +\infty$** :
\begin{align}
I(a)&:=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}}{a^2 + (\log x)^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac 1{a^2}\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^{-x}\left(-\left(\frac{\log x}a\right)^2\right)^{n}\,dx\\
&=\frac 1{a^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{a^{2n}}\int_0^{\infty}  e^{-x}\left(\frac d{ds}\right)^{2n}\left.e^{s\log x}\right|_{s=0}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{a^{2(n+1)}}\left(\frac d{ds}\right)^{2n}\left.\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} x^s\,dx\right|_{s=0}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{a^{2(n+1)}}\left.\Gamma^{(2n)}(1+s)\right|_{s=0}\\
\end{align}
Since $\;\Gamma^{(2n)}(1)\sim (2n)!\;$ the equality must be replaced by an asymptotic expansion :
$$\tag{1}\boxed{\displaystyle I(a)\sim \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac {(-1)^n\,\Gamma^{(2n)}(1)}{a^{2(n+1)}}},\quad a\to +\infty$$

The searched integral is thus a generating function for the even derivatives of $\,\Gamma$ at point $1$ :
it has the same expansion as  $\;\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(1+i/a)+\Gamma(1-i/a)}{2\,a^2}\;$ for $\,a\to +\infty$  but without the even factorials at the denominators (i.e. without convergence of the whole series for $a>1$).

Let's add that each derivative $\Gamma^{(n)}(1)$ may be rewritten using the expansion of $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(1+x)=\exp\left({-\gamma\,x+\sum_{ k=2}^\infty\;\zeta(k)\dfrac{(-x)^k}k}\right)\;$ to get :
$$\tag{2}\Gamma(1+x)=\overbrace{1}^{\Gamma(1)}-\gamma x+\overbrace{\left(\gamma^2+\zeta(2)\right)}^{\Gamma^{\large{(2)}}(1)}\frac{x^2}{2!}-\left(\gamma^3+3\gamma\,\zeta(2)+2\zeta(3)\right)\frac{x^3}{3!}+\overbrace{\left(\gamma^4+6\gamma^2\zeta(2)+8\gamma\,\zeta(3)+\frac{27}2\zeta(4)\right)}^{\Gamma^{\large{(4)}}(1)}\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$$

**Update:** An asymptotic expansion for a more general Laplace transform was given by Bouwkamp ([ref. $1$](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/fulltext.php?artid=21043&year=1972&volume=21) or [ref. $2$](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/1mv4g6g5)) for $\sigma\ge 0$ :
$$\tag{3}t^{\sigma}\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x^{\sigma-1}e^{-t\,x}}{a^2 + (\log x)^2}\,dx\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\varphi_n(a,\sigma)}{(\log t)^{n+1}}\qquad(t\to\infty)$$
with the coefficients $\varphi_n$ obtained from the generating function :
$$\tag{4}\frac{\sin(ax)}a\Gamma(\sigma+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varphi_n(a,\sigma)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

At this point it may be observed that if $I(a)$ is generalized to $\;\displaystyle I_{\sigma}(a):=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x^{\,\sigma-1}e^{-x}}{a^2 + (\log x)^2}\,dx\,$
then a derivation similar to the obtention of $(1)$ (with an additional factor $x^{\,\sigma-1}$ in the integral) will simply replace $\,\Gamma^{(2n)}(1+s)\,$ by $\,\Gamma^{(2n)}(\sigma+s)$ and produce :
$$\tag{1'}\boxed{\displaystyle I_{\sigma}(a)\sim \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac {(-1)^n\,\Gamma^{(2n)}(\sigma)}{a^{2(n+1)}}},\quad a\to +\infty$$

---

**Expansion as $a\to 0$**: it is very regular too with a simple pole at $0$.

The substitution $\;x:=e^{-w}\;$ gives :
\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {e^{-x}}{(\log x)^2+a^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}}{w^2+a^2}\,dw\\
&=-\frac 1a\;\operatorname{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}}{w+ia}\,dw\\
&=-\frac 1a\;\operatorname{Im}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{\large{ia-e^{ia}}}}{w+ia}\,dw+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{ia-e^{ia}}}}{w+ia}\,dw\right]\\
&=-\frac 1a\;\operatorname{Im}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{\large{ia-e^{ia}}}}{w+ia}\,dw-\pi i\, e^{\large{ia-e^{ia}}}\right]\\
\tag{5}I(a)&=E(a)+\frac{\pi}a\;\operatorname{Re}\left[e^{\large{ia-e^{\,ia}}}\right]\\
\end{align}

The odd part of $I(a)$ is given in closed form (at the right) so let's study the even part :
$$\tag{6}E(a):=-\frac 1a\;\operatorname{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{\large{ia-e^{ia}}}}{w+ia}\,dw=\sum_{n\ge 0} K_{2n}\, a^{2n}$$
The integrand is an entire function (since of type $\,h_a(w):=\dfrac {f(w)-f(-ia)}{w-(-ia)},\ h_a(-ia)=f'(-ia)\;$ with $f(w):=e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}$ entire) and may thus be expanded in power series of $a$ as :
$$\tag{7}h_a(w)=\frac 1w\left[ e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{-1}\sum_{n\ge 0}\dfrac{\overline{B}_{n+1}}{n!}(ia)^n\right]\sum_{m\ge 0} \left(-\frac{ia}w\right)^m$$

where $\,\overline{B}_n\,$ is the $n$-th ["complementary Bell number"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementaryBellNumber.html) generated by $\,e^{\large{1-e^{x}}}\,$ (with a shift of $1$ from the multiplication by $e^x$).

This allows to obtain integrals for the $K_{2n}$ coefficients of $\, a^{2n}$ (from $(6)$ we need only the imaginary part) :
$$\tag{8} K_{2n}= \frac{(-1)^n}e\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\large{\,1-w-e^{-w}}}-1}{w^{2n+2}}+\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{\overline{B}_{2n+3}}{(k+2)!\,(-w)^{2n-k}}\;dw,\quad n>0$$
while $K_0$ may be integrated by parts and rewritten (using $\;x=e^{-w}\,$) as :

\begin{align}
K_0&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{-1}}{w^{2}}dw\\
&=\left.-\frac 1x\left(e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}-e^{-1}\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {e^{-w}-1}x\,e^{\large{-w-e^{-w}}}\,dw\\
&=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac {x-1}{\log x}\,e^{-x}\,dx,\quad\text{but}\ \frac {x-1}{\log x}=\int_0^1 x^t\,dt\ \ \text{so that}\\
&=-\int_0^1\int_0^{\infty}x^{t}e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=-\int_0^1\Gamma(1+t)\,dt\\
\end{align}

Concerning numerical evaluation you may use :
$$\tag{9}I(a)\approx \sum_{n=0} K_{2n} a^{2n}+\frac{\pi}a\;\operatorname{Re}\left[e^{\large{ia-e^{\,ia}}}\right]$$

with
\begin{align}
K_0&\approx -0.9227459506806306051438804823457555774372343917106859152 \\
K_2&\approx -0.2818432097003410734482737060285029254823027754542059884\\
K_4&\approx -0.010603155563385929453669193499488685330976821362\\
K_6&\approx +0.01391725152703237611983369670383107076359973\\
K_8&\approx +0.002934676571947851378554083839156926455\\
K_{10}&\approx -0.000021228852199696308226770734336
\end{align}
Note that the coefficients of $\,a^{2n-1}\,$ are too related to the complementary Bell numbers by $\;\displaystyle K_{2n-1}=-(-1)^n\frac{\overline{B}_{2n+1}}{(2n)!}\,\frac {\pi}e\;$ with the odd part expanded as :
$$\frac {\pi}e\left[\frac 1a+\frac a{2!}+\frac{2\,a^3}{4!}-\frac{9\,a^5}{6!}-\frac{267\,a^7}{8!}-\frac{2180\,a^9}{10!}+\cdots\right]$$

**Ref:**

1. C. J. Bouwkamp $(1972)$ ["Note on an asymptotic expansion"](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/fulltext.php?artid=21043&year=1972&volume=21).
2. S. G. Llewellyn Smith $(2000)$ ["The asymptotic behaviour of Ramanujan's integral and its application to two-dimensional diffusion-like equations"](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/1mv4g6g5).
3. R. Wong $(1975)$ ["On Laplace transforms near the origin"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-130/S0025-5718-1975-0367564-1)